# nodejs (express) is it possible to have case insensitive querystring?

Tags: node.js, express

It seems that querystring is case sensitive. Is it possible to have a case insensitive querystring?

If my url has `?Id=10`, accessing `req.query.id` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's not possible as-is, but you could insert a very simple middleware which would, for instance, lowercase all keys in `req.query`:

```
// insert this before your routes
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  for (var key in req.query)
  { 
    req.query[key.toLowerCase()] = req.query[key];
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Coming from IIS, this feels weird that such basic requirement is overlooked.

Comment: Perhaps in the IIS-world, using query parameters with mixes case are more common than elsewhere :) I've always used lowercase parameters myself.

Comment: what if a user types query params with mixed cases? :)

Comment: In what way would a user create query *parameters* with mixed case? You mean by editing the URL directly?

Comment: Yes. I might go to `example.com?bookid=1` where as server is expecting `?bookId=1` which is pretty common scenario.

Comment: If that's a common scenario for you (it isn't for me), I completely understand your requirement for a case-insensitive way of accessing those parameters :)

Comment: @robertklep , If I am not wrong , we will end up with double the properties.. right

Comment: @CleanCrispCode yes, that's right. If that's a problem, it's easy to work around, though.

Answer (score 15):

With the solution proposed by Robert, be aware that whenever you *read* from `req.query`, you will need to use lowercased keys. This makes future additions to your API error prone.

Here is an alternative piece of middleware, using a [Proxy object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to modify the behavior of `req.query[...]`, so that lookups are case insensitive:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.query = new Proxy(req.query, {
    get: (target, name) => target[Object.keys(target)
      .find(key => key.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase())]
  })

  next();
});
```

Besides being less error prone, this approach also leaves the `req.query` intact for enumerating operations, where the original solution would potentially create duplicate key/value pairs.

Comment: remember to return `target[name]` at the last condition, or the Object methods such as query.toString() will throw error.

Answer (score 0):

If both the parameter and its values are to be treated case-insensitively then there's a simple approach:

```
const express = require('express');
const qs = require('qs');
const app = express();

app.set('query parser', function(str) {
    // See https://github.com/ljharb/qs/blob/410bdd3c8ae7f5d7ae9b52648b8642b8adc5e1c0/dist/qs.js#L47 
    return qs.parse(typeof str === 'string' ? str.toUpperCase() : str, {});
});
```

That is, simply upper-case (or lower if you prefer) the entire query string before it is parsed.